# Going from Ubuntu willy 15.10 to xenial xerus failing

Tags: 16.04, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

I wanted to install docker on my ubuntu 15.04 (vivid) but it seems not supported so I upgraded to 15.10 (willy) by using this sources.list:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

and `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. It did not show any error and my apt-get update is working.

I then started doing a do-release-update towards 16.04 (Xenial), however some downloads are always failing and it won't proceed to the end.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: The Ubuntu versions 15.04 and 15.10 have passed end of life, and receive no updates, not even security updates. Please backup all files, that you want to keep, and make a fresh installation of a current version. I suggest that you try Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, the newest version with long time support (at least until April 2023).

Comment: I heard that before. Is there no way to bypass this ?( without doing a fresh install ?)

Comment: It is complicated to do-release-update and if you need several steps, it is very likely to fail. It is usually easier and faster to make a fresh installation, copy the files you have backed up, install the programs you need *now* and do the configurations, that you want *now*. This way you will also get a much cleaner and more efficient system (compared to an upgraded system with a lot of old stuff, that you might not need, and that may cause conflicts).

Comment: You are welcome to ask new questions after the fresh installation, if you need. Good luck :-)

Comment: I did not try the last step but everything with update-manager core but otherwise the answer of the question mentioned was the starting point of my question